# Can you still distribute legacy safari extensions?

Tags: safari-extension

I have a legacy safari extension.  I understand that I will not be able to distribute it through the Mac App Store. On the apple developer website it says it is possible to notarize the app and distribute it outside the store. I am having difficulty in figuring out how to notarize a safari legacy extension and prepare it for distribution outside the store.